# MYSQL column count doesnt match with value count at row 1 nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs

I know there are many questions like this but I genuinely don't know whats wrong. I have a table with 4 columns (Id, teacherId, class, attendanceRecord). The Id column is auto incrementing. This is the backend:

```
app.post("/api/attendanceRecord", async(req, res) => {
    const students = req.body.students
    const className = req.body.className
    const teacherId = req.body.teacherId

    connection.query(
        "INSERT INTO attendance(teacherId, class, attendanceRecord) VALUES(?,?,?)",
        [teacherId, className, students],
        (err, result) => {
            if (result){
                res.send({ message: result })
            } 
            if (err){
                res.send({ message: err })
                console.log(err)
            }
        }
    )
})
```

This is the front end:

```
  const updateAbsent = () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:1337/api/attendanceRecord", {
      teacherId: teacherId,
      className: className,
      students: students
    }).then((response) => {
    if(response){
      console.log(response)
    } else{
      console.log("error")
    }
  })

  }
```

attendance table:

```
CREATE TABLE attendance(
    ID INT auto_increment,
    teacherId INT,
    class varchar(255),
    attendanceRecord VARCHAR(1000),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please add the table definition to the question.

Comment: @TheImpaler I updated it

Comment: That's not a valid table in MySQL. Only the primary key can be auto_increment.

Comment: @TheImpaler Sorry that was an old query, the new query I used for the table is posted now

Comment: Works well for me. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3nABFnWBunpTZf6yT417kw/0. Maybe the parameters are sketchy. I would display them.

Comment: @TheImpaler ahhh I'm not sure. It could be my students paramater because it's an object

Comment: @TheImpaler Thank you for your help, i've solved the problem now :)